# How to distribute elements from map so that sum of elements should not increase upper bound

Tags: java, logic

Below is my problem with proper comments , where you need to write the logic inside the loop in which you have to do below things:
1-Print random counts from each statuses but count should not exceed actual count present in map(statusCount).
2-All statuses present in list should be included.
3-If I add all the printed count it should be equal to sampleSize i.e. 100

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Upper bound
        int sampleSize = 100;
        
        //All statuses
        final List<Integer> statuses = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        statuses.add(15100);
        statuses.add(15500);
        statuses.add(15300);
        statuses.add(15000);
        
        //All status count
        final Map<Integer, Integer> statusCount = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        statusCount.put(15100, 70);
        statusCount.put(15500, 200);
        statusCount.put(15300, 370);
        statusCount.put(15000, 20);
        
        //Print random counts from each statuses.
        //All statuses should be included.
        //If i add all the printed count it should be equal to sampleSize i.e. 100
        for(Integer status : statuses) {
            
                    
            
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I tend to use `printf` when printing to console. Of course, you'll need a loop to print an array such as

```
for (int i = 0; i < _countof(statuses); i++)
{
    printf(statuses[i]);
}
```

I recommend not including `//Please write your code here.` if you want people to help. Also this isn't c.